# WordPress product review

Tags: review

Can someone suggest how can I make a top specsheet and benchmarks for a product like laptops and mobiles in WordPress as done in top review sites.

What are the relevant tools, plugins, resources and websites.

Answer (score 0):

First you would create a custom post type "products", you can use [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) for this. You can also do it [by hand](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).

Then you would create custom fields for the products, you can use the excellent [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) for this. Here's some [resources from the Wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).